# Can't read from file "http://<SITE_URL>/rest/default/schema?services=all" in Magento 2.2.6

Tags: magento2, rest-api, swagger

[image]

And Error response is

```
{"schemaValidationMessages":[{"level":"error","message":"Can't read from file http://<SITE_URL>/rest/default/schema?services=all"}]}
```

Comment: i think its working well with magento 2.3 i have just tested http://magento.amanweb.in/rest/default/schema?services=all however if not working for you please check file permission ones.

Comment: Yes, I've already checked it's working in 2.3 but not working in 2.2.6. Event I had tried using 777 file permission already. I am looking solution for version 2.2.6.

Answer (score 2):

The given url only supports the store code **default**.

In the latest version of magento 2 it is possible to change through the url parameter store.

If your version doesn’t support it yet just overwrite the swagger template file and replace default with your store code.